# A function to enter the ajax result in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, function

I have a problem with this code.
This happens:
just launch the code from console.log I get null, if I press the update button function works.

why is this happening?
how do I fix?

```
var urljson = "data_json.php";
var data = null;
var jqXHR = $.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: urljson,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: successHandler

});
function successHandler(result) {
     data = result; 
 }

function update(){
var jqXHR = $.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: urljson,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: successHandler

});
function successHandler(result) {
     data = result; 
 }
}

$(document).ready(function(){   

 console.log(data) //// null

});


document.getElementById('update').addEventListener('click', function() {

update();

console.log(data) //// Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, other 3213… ]

});
```

Comment: On document.ready event, the JSON hasn't returned from the server yet, so data is still null. It's only when the JSON file arrives and the succesHandler gets triggered, that data gets set.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax()` returns results asynchronously. Use `success` handler or `.then()` chained to `$.ajax()` to process response returned from request.

```
function update() {
  var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urljson,
    dataType: "json",
    success: successHandler    
  });

  function successHandler(result) {
    data = result;
    // do stuff with `data` here
    console.log(data);
  }
}

$(document).ready(update);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/89jkzzyk/

Comment: it works, but how do I work with the "date" variable in the "$(document) .ready(update)"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Access the result of `$.ajax()` response within `success` callback or `.then()` callback.

Comment: I'm trying to use the date variable in this way but does not work:

$(document).ready(update), function(){

var length = data.length;

console.log(length)
};

Comment: Perform tasks on `data` within `$.ajax()` `success` callback. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I know but I wish I need that "data" are updated every few minutes without the party of code contained in the "success" is updated

Comment: _" but I wish I need that "data" are updated every few minutes without the party of code contained in the "success" is updated"_ Updating every few minutes does not appear at original Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, `update()` is not getting called, thus `data` is null. Add your function call to `$(document).ready()` and it should work.

Comment: the var jqXHR does exactly the same as update(), so although it's true that update() doesn't get called, changing `$(document).ready(function(){   console.log(data) });` to `$(document).ready(function(){   update();console.log(data) });` still won't work. Data only gets set once the xhr call triggers successHandler, so anything done with the data should go into the successHandler, not into the document.ready The click event only works because the jqXHR on script load already fetched the json file by the time update() gets called by the click.